# How to save array data in nodejs using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, async-await, async.js

I am stuck to save data in mongoDb. Here data is in array and i need to insert data if mongodb does not have. Please look code:-

```
var contactPersonData = [{
    Name: 'Mr. Bah',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'Mr. Sel',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'Mr.ATEL',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'ANISH',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'sunny ji',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'ashish',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}]
console.log('filedata', contactPersonData);
var escapeData = [];
var tempArr = [];

function saveContact(personObj, mainCallback) {
    var tempC = personObj['Organization'].trim();
    var insertData = {};
    Contact.findOne({ companyName: tempC })
        .exec(function(err, contact) {
            if (err)
                return mainCallback(err);
            console.log('find com', contact)
            if (contact) {
                //document exists
                mainCallback(null, insertData);
            } else {
                var newContact = new Contact({ companyName: tempC, createdBy: '58ae5d18ba71d4056f30f7b1' });
                newContact.save(function(err, contact) {
                    if (err)
                        return mainCallback(err);
                    console.log('new contact', contact)
                    insertData.contactId = contact._id;
                    insertData.name = personObj['Name'];
                    insertData.email = personObj['Email'];
                    insertData.contactNumber = { number: personObj['Phone'] };
                    insertData.designation = personObj['Designation'];
                    tempArr.push(insertData);
                    mainCallback(null, insertData);
                })
            }

        });
}
async.map(contactPersonData, saveContact, function(err, result) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
    },
    function(err) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);
        res.status(200).json({ unsaved: escapeData })

    })
```

As per above code it has to insert six document instead of one. I think that above iteration not wait to complete previous one. So, the `if` condition is always `false` and `else` is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `saveContact()` function is fine. The reason you get 6 documents instead of 1 document is that `async.map()` runs you code in parallel. All the 6 requests are made in parallel, not one after the another.

From the `async.map()` function's documentation -

> Note, that since this function applies the iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

As a result before the document is created in your database all queries are already run and all the 6 queries are not able to find that document since its still in the process of creation. Therefore your `saveContact()` method creates all the 6 documents.

If you run your code again then no more documents will be formed because by that time your document would be formed.

You should try running your code using `async.mapSeries()` to process your request serially. Just replace `map()` with `mapSeries()` in your above code. This way it will wait for one request to complete and then execute another and as a result only one document will be created. More on `async.mapSeries()` [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries).

Comment: there is no any `async.serial()` method.  There is `async.series()` method but i could not understand how to run this method with loop i.e, `contactPersonData` at above question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `async.map()` wrong.

First, [async.map()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) only has 3 parameters (i.e. `coll`, `iteratee`, and `callback`) so why do you have 4? In your case, `coll` is your `contactPersonData`, `iteratee` is your `saveContact` function, and `callback` is an anonymous function.

Second, the whole point of using `async.map()` is to create a new array. You are not using it that way and, instead, are using it more like an [`async.each()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

Third, you probably should loop through the elements sequentially and not in parallel. Therefore, you should use [async.mapSeries()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) instead of `async.map()`.

Here's how I would revise/shorten your code:

```
var contactPersonData = [{
    Name: 'Mr. Bah',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'Mr. Sel',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'Mr.ATEL',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'ANISH',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'sunny ji',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}, {
    Name: 'ashish',
    Organization: 'Ashima Limited - Point 2'
}];

function saveContact(personObj, mainCallback) {
    var tempC = personObj.Organization.trim();
    Contact.findOne({ companyName: tempC }, function (err, contact) {
        if (err)
            return mainCallback(err);
        console.log('found contact', contact);
        // document exists, so mark it as complete and pass the old item
        if (contact) 
            return mainCallback(null, contact);
        // document does not exist, so add it
        contact = new Contact({ companyName: tempC, createdBy: '58ae5d18ba71d4056f30f7b1' });
        contact.save(function (err, contact) {
            if (err)
                return mainCallback(err);
            console.log('created new contact', contact)
            // mark it as complete and pass a new/transformed item
            mainCallback(null, {
                contactId: contact._id,
                name: personObj.Name,
                email: personObj.Email, // ??
                contactNumber: { number: personObj.Phone }, // ??
                designation: personObj.Designation // ??
            });
        });
    });
};

async.mapSeries(contactPersonData, saveContact, function (err, contacts) {
    if (err)
        return next(err);
    // at this point, contacts will have an array of your old and new/transformed items
    console.log('transformed contacts', contacts);
    res.json({ unsaved: contacts });
});
```

In terms of `??` comments, it means you don't have these properties in your `contactPersonData` and would therefore be `undefined`.